# How to Zoom-In an Image Using Magnific Popup's open() Method

Tags: css, jquery-ui, zooming, magnific-popup, class-method

The following code is used to trigger a Magnific pop-up when a page loads.  Unfortunately, nearly all of the documentation provided by Dmitry Semenov (the author) focuses on three other initialization procedures.

$.magnificPopup.open({... various key-value pairs ...});

My goal is to have the initial item of a gallery zoom in when a page opens.  I believe that I could accomplish this task through experimentation, if only I knew how to call Magnific Pop-Up's generic classes with the open() function.

In particular, the zoom-in effect requires both an image and its thumb.  Although I have been successful with the use of the **src** key for calling up the original image, I do not know how to call the image's thumb.

Maybe someone could supply a paragraph of code with comment, and I could learn enough from your example to advance on my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gallery img:first-child").click();
```

Should do the trick. Make sure you add that to the document.ready jQuery initialisation code.